# How to find paragraphs that comes under a header 1 using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word in C#?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I'm a learner in using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`. Consider I have a word document with headings in style 'Header1' and some sentences of style 'normal' comes under it. Now I need to find those lines that comes under a paragraph of style 'Header 1'. This is what I have been coded so for:

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph paragraph in doc.Paragraphs)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Style style = paragraph.get_Style() as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Style;
    string styleName = style.NameLocal;
    string text = paragraph.Range.Text;
    if (styleName == "Heading 1")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Sent lines :" + text.ToString()); //this will show all headings
    }
}
```

How do I display the all lines that comes under those headings?

Comment: I'm confused, the code is testing for "Heading 1" however your question refers to 'Header1' and later 'Header 1'. Also confused at "lines that comes under a paragraph of style 'Header 1'" . Do you mean you want to get the text from the paragraphs after/below these headings? Can you clear up the question?

Comment: @jJack ,Yes I need to find the text that comes under Heading 1, I'm sorry for the misinterpretation.

Comment: Well the code I put in my answer is all you need then. "Works for me". Does it work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately checking the style.NameLocal makes your code dependent from the current language used by Word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this, assuming I understand your question:

```
//get the 'next' paragraph but only if it exists
if (paragraph.Next() != null)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Next paragraph:" + paragraph.Next().Range.Text.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Why you are using `Text.ToString()`? Isn't Text in in self a string?